# PHP Upload file from Image variable

Tags: php, image, upload

My Idea is to upload a image file that is combined with a watermark. This code needs to work like this. On a portfolio website, the owner uploads an image he wants to sell throught the CMS i made. But because he wants to sell the image he wants it to come on the site with a watermark.

So my idea, i let him upload the original image, then i get the image through the $_Files() en combine it with a watermark, make it one image again and upload that image.

Now is my question, how do i upload a image created in PHP i tried to convert it to Base64 but with no luck. Here is my code.

Sorry for the bad english!

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);


$filetype =  substr($target_file, -4);

if($filetype == ".gif") $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($filetype == ".jpg") $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($filetype == ".png") $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if (empty($image)) die();
$watermark = @imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
$imagewidth = imagesx($image);
$imageheight = imagesy($image);
$watermarkwidth = imagesx($watermark);
$watermarkheight = imagesy($watermark);
$startwidth = (($imagewidth - $watermarkwidth)/2);
$startheight = (($imageheight - $watermarkheight)/2);
imagecopy($image, $watermark,  $startwidth, $startheight, 0, 0, $watermarkwidth, $watermarkheight);

file_put_contents($target_file, $image)
```

Comment: `imagejpeg` should do the trick -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php (instead of `file_put_contents`)

Comment: I think you use use `move_uploaded_file` first to "upload" the file to a temp folder, then manipulate it however you need, then save it to its final location.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I think you don't have to use `move_uploaded_file`, because the file is already in a temporary directory. but if the OP want's to save the original file he should use it to save the image on the server in addition to the watermarked one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`imagejpeg($image, $target_file);`
or `imagepng($image, $target_file);`
or `imagegif($image, $target_file);`